# Is it possible to tell if the OpenGL version is OpenGL ES within the shader code?

Tags: opengl-es, preprocessor, version, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

Is there any way to tell within the source code for a shader that the shader is being compiled for OpenGL ES? I want to be able to define the version using the `#version` preprocessor directive to be 100 for OpenGL ES (so that the shader compiles for OpenGL ES 2.0), but is version 110 for OpenGL 2.1).

Is the best way to do this to place the #version as a separate string which is fed in at the application level, or is there a way to to do this within the shader?

Another useful, related thing to be able to do would be to say something like
`#if version == 100` compile this code, `else` compile this code. Is this possible within GLSL?

Thanks.

Comment: couldn't you find that out in your C program where you load the shader and prepend `#version 100` if it's OpenGL ES and otherwise `#version 110`. I mean you have to pass OpenGL the shader as a string anyways, so why not do the version processing in C.

Comment: Yea I was thinking that was what I was going to have to do!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prepending `#version` from the main program as PeterT suggested in the above comment is the *only* way that will work. Being able to do this (and being able to define constants without having something like a `-D` compiler switch available) is the main intent behind `glShaderSource` taking an array of pointers rather than a simple `char*`.

The GLSL specification (chapter 3.3) requires that `#version` be the first thing in a shader source, except for whitespace and comments.

Thus, no such thing as

```
#ifdef foo
    #version 123
#endif
```

is valid, and no such thing will compile (unless the shader compiler is overly permissive, i.e. broken).

About your second question, conditional compilation certainly works and using it in the way you intend to do is a good thing.

Comment: Kk so I started doing exactly that and it seems to work really well. The only thing is I suggested that you check the version using `#if version == 100` but instead you should use the built-in value `__VERSION__`, so it would be, `#if __VERSION__ == 100`, for example.

Comment: The easiest thing I found to do is just compiler switch & prepend the version string from your C++/main source

Answer (score 5):

This is also related information:

http://blog.beuc.net/posts/OpenGL_ES_2.0_using_Android_NDK/

You can, for example:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif
```

OpenGL ES 2.0 implementations are required to have a GL_ES macro predefined in the shaders.